# SmtpClient.Send() removing <details> html tag

Tags: c#, html, smtp, smtpclient

For example, take this class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MailAddress foo = new MailAddress("foo@bar.net");
        MailAddress bar = new MailAddress("foo@bar.net");
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(foo, bar);
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Body= @"
          <html>
            <body>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <details>
                    <summary>
                      List <span>- Owner</span>
                    </summary>
                    <ul >
                      <li>Test<span> Someone</span></li>
                      <li>test A <span>- Someone</span></li>
                      <li>Test B <span>- Someone</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </details>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </body>
          </html>";
        msg.Subject = "Test";
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("10.1.0.6",25);
        client.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

If I try to send this e-mail, everytime it will arrive without the `<details>` and `<summary>` tags. If, after recieving the e-mail I open Chrome's developer tools and manually insert the tags again at the same place, they magically work.
Is it a bug in SmtpClient? Or should I format my e-mail differently?

Comment: It will almost certainly be the receiving email server that strips out nonsense HTML. Can you use a `div` instead?

Comment: You mean a '<div>' instead of '<details>'? I guess not, my intention was to achieve something like this: http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-tree-menu-framework but with expandable items

Comment: Remember that you need to treat HTML in emails as if you're writing it in 1995. Virtually every email client will fail to render complex/modern HTML.

Comment: HTML emails are a black art, you simply cannot compare email rendering with the way the same markup looks in a browser. http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email

Comment: I guess so... is there any other tag which has a similar function?

Comment: I suspect you are getting a long line.  Try this :msg.Body = 
"<html>\n" +
"<body>\n" +
"<ul>\n" +
"<li>\n" +
"<details>\n" +
"<summary>\n" +
"List <span>- Owner</span>\n" +
"</summary>\n" +
"<ul >\n" +
"<li>Test<span> Someone</span></li>\n" +
"<li>test A <span>- Someone</span></li>\n" +
"<li>Test B <span>- Someone</span></li>\n" +
"</ul>\n" +
"</details>\n" +
"</li>\n" +
"</ul>\n" +
"</body>\n" +
"</html>";

Comment: @jdweng doesn't work, unfortunately